# Can an IBM ServeRAID 4mx controller work on a non-IBM server?

Tags: raid, scsi, controller, ibm

I have some IBM ServeRAID 4mx controllers on some aging IBM x360 servers (Pentium III 1.5 ghz CPUs); I also have a SCSI disk array with two ports, which can be attached to those controllers; and I have two more recent servers which would be a lot more useful than the x360s for the clustered application I want to run. But those servers aren't from IBM.

The controllers use a standard PCI-X bus, and have their own SCSI ports; they don't *seem* to have that super-tight integration with the server motheboard that can be seen on other ServeRAID models.

Can those controllers work on non-IBM servers which have a standard PCI-X slot available?

I know the best answer would be "put them on another server and see what happens", but I don't have any available server at the moment, and I need management approval to reconfigure the two servers I'd like to use.

Support isn't an issue here, all the involved hardware is out of warranty; I'd just like to know if anyone ever succeeded in using an IBM ServeRAID 4mx controller on a non-IBM server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work. I've got an old IBM Ultra 160 controller in a whitebox, and I have a HP controller in a Dell.

Actually I just looked at it, and it's an IBM 4mx!

Comment: Great, thanks. BTW, this requirement for comments to be longer than 15 chars is really a pain sometimes...